# Visual Studio 2019 shows "The program '[1456] regsvr32.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3)" when I press "F5" and is not launching my Unreal Engine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

At first I would like to say that recently I had my entire PC formatted. After that I installed both my Unreal Engine and Visual Studio 2019 at locations that were different from where they were before formatting.

At first I tried to open my project solution and tried building my solution with "F5". But it gave me an error [The screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM9kg.jpg). The error stated "Unable to start the program  System cannot find the path specified". The path in that error message was the path that existed before formatting my PC.

Alternate link to the error screenshot: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjZEJUZlPM7yizRT67cRETCHmIwY

Then I Uninstalled and reinstalled my UE4 and from there I launched my project and tried opening the Visual Studio files from the Editor. It did open the files, but the UE4 and the VS were not quite in sync. Some of the details that I hardcoded from VS through my codes were not quite showing up on my Unreal Editor.
I tried closing the UE4 and build my code again this time with F5. But this time The output log shows the line "Specified Path not found" for a temporary duration of time and then quickly it changes to this,

```
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AcLayers.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sfc.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sfc_os.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'regsvr32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. 
The thread 0xab4 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The program '[17104] regsvr32.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Then I saw couple of fixes here in the stack overflow only, and I tried them out, these fixes are:

**1.** I went to *Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run* and I checked, under "On Run, when projects are out of date", the option was set to "Always Build" and under "On Run when build or deployment error occur", the option was set to "Prompt to launch". But nothing was launching and no prompt was showing too.

**2.** I searched for the exited with code 3 and there I found it said that it means the specific path file is not found and it can be fixed using ILMerge, so I searched ILMerge and from this website (https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/06/automate-ilmerge-for-workflowsplugins-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one-in-dynamics-365/) I found that Ill have to install ILMerge through the "Package Manager Console" in the "NutGet package manager". and I installed it using these two command lines, **Install-Package ILMerge.MSBuild.Task** and **Install-Package ilmerge**. Both of them showed successfully installed. But then I tried F5 again, but its the same.

**3.** I also went to *Tools->Options->Debugging->General* and at the very bottom, I checked the box for "Automatically close the console while debugging stops", which was unchecked by default.

**4.** At last I tried cleaning up my solution from the "Build" option and the I hit F5, this time the output that came was different and it showed that it had errors and it also prompted whether I want to launch the application or not. This is the output that I got,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Alpha1, Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------
1>Creating makefile for Alpha1Editor (no existing makefile)
1>Parsing headers for Alpha1Editor
1>  Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Alpha1.uproject" "D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Intermediate\Build\Win64\Alpha1Editor\Development\Alpha1Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -abslog="C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_UHT.txt" -installed
1>Reflection code generated for Alpha1Editor in 7.5102243 seconds
1>Building Alpha1Editor...
1>Using Visual Studio 2019 14.26.28806 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
1>Building 41 actions with 4 processes...
1>  [1/41] Default.rc2
1>  [2/41] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.cpp
1>  [3/41] ColliderMovementComponent.cpp
1>EXEC : error : Unable to rename D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\Alpha1\ColliderMovementComponent.cpp.txt.tmp to D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\Alpha1\ColliderMovementComponent.cpp.txt
1>  [4/41] Collider.cpp
1>  [5/41] Critter.cpp
1>  [6/41] Enemy.cpp
1>  [7/41] FloatingPlatform.cpp
1>  [8/41] EnemyAnimInstance.cpp
1>  [9/41] Weapon.cpp
1>  [10/41] FloorSwitch.cpp
1>  [11/41] MyActor.cpp
1>D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Source\Alpha1\MyActor.cpp(50): warning C4996: 'UPrimitiveComponent::AddTorque': Use AddTorqueInRadians instead. Please update your code to the new API before upgrading to the next release, otherwise your project will no longer compile.
1>  [12/41] Item.cpp
1>  [13/41] MainAnimInstance.cpp
1>  [14/41] Pickup.cpp
1>  [15/41] Main.cpp
1>  [16/41] Alpha1GameModeBase.cpp
1>  [17/41] Explosive.cpp
1>  [18/41] Alpha1.cpp
1>  [19/41] Alpha1.init.gen.cpp
1>  [20/41] SpawnVolume.cpp
1>  [21/41] Collider.gen.cpp
1>  [22/41] Critter.gen.cpp
1>  [23/41] ColliderMovementComponent.gen.cpp
1>  [24/41] EnemyAnimInstance.gen.cpp
1>  [25/41] Enemy.gen.cpp
1>  [26/41] Explosive.gen.cpp
1>  [27/41] FloatingPlatform.gen.cpp
1>  [28/41] Alpha1GameModeBase.gen.cpp
1>  [29/41] FloorSwitch.gen.cpp
1>  [30/41] MainAnimInstance.gen.cpp
1>  [31/41] Main.gen.cpp
1>  [32/41] MyActor.gen.cpp
1>  [33/41] Pickup.gen.cpp
1>  [34/41] SpawnVolume.gen.cpp
1>  [35/41] Weapon.gen.cpp
1>EXEC : error : Unable to rename D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\Alpha1\Weapon.gen.cpp.txt.tmp to D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\Alpha1\Weapon.gen.cpp.txt
1>  [36/41] Alpha1_PlayerController.gen.cpp
1>  [37/41] Item.gen.cpp
1>  [38/41] Alpha1_PlayerController.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(46,5): error MSB3073: The command "chcp 65001 >NUL && D:\UE_4.25\UE_4.25\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat Alpha1Editor Win64 Development -Project="D:\AlphaGames\Alpha1\Alpha1.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.
1>Done building project "Alpha1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please assist me with this issue. I am stuck with this problem for a long time. Tell me I f you want to know anything else or want me to share any other info about this issue. Let me know if you face issues in accessing the error screenshot link that I shared

Answer (score 0):

Somebody from my team just had the exact same issue as what you described for your 4th fix attempt (the rename error). It appears to have been caused by their antivirus software, preventing the file mentioned in the error message to be renamed.
I'd advise you to completely disable the antivirus while you are building.

I've read similar errors can also be caused by special characters in the file path, or the path being too long (over 260).